# Doing calculations between columns of different dataframe where something like a for loop is included using Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following to dataframes

```
DF1:
+----------+----------+---------+
|     Place|       lat|      lon|
+----------+----------+---------+
|         A|       X_A|      Y_A|
|         B|       X_B|      Y_B|
|         C|       X_C|      Y_C|
+----------+----------+---------+

DF2:
+----------+----------+---------+
|      City|       lat|      lon|
+----------+----------+---------+
|         D|       X_D|      Y_D|
|         E|       X_E|      Y_E|
|         F|       X_F|      Y_F|
|         G|       X_G|      Y_G|
|         H|       X_H|      Y_H|
|         I|       X_I|      Y_I|
+----------+----------+---------+
```

What I want to obtain is the shortest euclidean distance from Place (from DF1) to City(from DF2)

So what I have to do is:
first calculate the distance of Place A to the cities D until I and then decide the shortest distance based on the calculation.

So the pseudocode is something showed below containing a nested for loop:

```
for (places = ranging from A until C){
   X1 = places.lat
   Y1 = places.lon
   for (city = ranging from D until I){
       X2 = city.lat
       Y2 = city.lon
       list d = sqrt((X2-X1)^2 - (Y2-Y1)^2))
   res[place] = min(d)}
```

where `res[]` is actually a column in a dataframe containing the shortest distance.

So what I first thought is using a `CrossJoin()` between the two dataframes, but then I don't know how I should continue after that step.

So can help anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've done your cross join, you can compute euclidean distance using [`hypot` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#hypot(l:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,r:Double):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and store it into a `distance` column with [`withColumn` dataset method](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) and then get minimum value of this column by grouping by `Place` column aggregating `distance` column with [`min` aggregate function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#min(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

Here is the complete code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.hypot

df1.crossJoin(df2)
  .withColumn("distance", hypot(df1.col("lat") - df2.col("lat"), df1.col("lon") - df2.col("lon")))
  .groupBy("Place")
  .agg(functions.min("distance").as("min_distance"))
```

You will get a dataframe with two columns, similar to the following one:

```
+-----+-----------------+
|Place|min_distance     |
+-----+-----------------+
|B    |2.68700576850888 |
|C    |2.545584412271571|
|A    |2.82842712474619 |
+-----+-----------------+
```

Comment: How is the scalability of this method? Because I have a really large set of data

Comment: This method is not really scalable. It is due to `crossJoin`: if for instance you have 1 million rows in `DF1` and 1 million rows in `DF2`, after `crossJoin` step you get a dataframe with 1 trillion rows (1 million multiplied by 1 million) which can be very slow to proceed. What are the size of your dataframes (number of places and number of cities) ?

Comment: The number of cities is not much. Around 20-30, but the number of Places is around 400.000

Comment: As you don't have that much data (400000x30 is only 12 millions) this solution should work without any issue. However, as your cities dataset is very small, I think it is wiser to collect it and distribute it over all your places. See [my second answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69753698/6807769) to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only few cities, I would say less than 1000 cities, you can avoid `crossjoin`, `groupBy` and all the related shuffles that may slow your Spark job:

- First, collect all cities latitudes and longitudes in a `citiesPositions` array
- Then, add a new column `min_distance` to your dataframe, filling this column as follows:

  - Convert your `citiesPositions` array to a column with [`typedLit` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#typedLit%5BT%5D(literal:T)(implicitevidence$1:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
  - Then, apply [`hypot` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#hypot(l:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,r:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to all elements of this array using [`transform` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#transform(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
  - Finally, take the smallest element of this array with [`array_min` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#array_min(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

You can code this as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_min, col, hypot, transform, typedLit}

val citiesPositions = df2.select("lat", "lon")
  .collect()
  .map(row => (row.getDouble(0), row.getDouble(1)))

df1.withColumn(
  "min_distance", 
  array_min(
    transform(
      typedLit(citiesPositions), 
      x => hypot(col("lat") - x.getItem("_1"), col("lon") - x.getItem("_2"))
    )
  )
)
```

This code works with Spark 3.0 and greater. If you're on a version of Spark before 3.0, you should replace columns transformation with an user-defined function